# A modular conjecture about odd primes

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, conjectures

Conjecture:
$n^{2p-1}\equiv n\pmod {2p}$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ and all odd primes $p$.

I started investigate the least $x_n$ such that $p_n^{p_{n+1}}\equiv x_n\pmod{p_{n+2}}$ and ended up with this for me unknown conjecture. I've tested it for a lot of random values of $n$ and $p$.

Comment: What is $x$ ? What is the conjecture ?

Comment: This follows from Little Fermat.  Sketch:  if $\gcd (n,p)=1$  then $n^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p\implies n^{2p-2}\equiv 1 \pmod p\implies n^{2p-1}\equiv n\pmod p$.  (it's obvious that the two sides have the same parity $\pmod 2$).

Comment: @donald: well, I investigated the least x...

Comment: @lulu: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely $n^{2p-1}-n$ is always even then it remains to show that $p$ divides $n^{2p-1}-n$. If $p\mid n$ it's obvious and if $p\nmid n$ it is true according to Fermat's little theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Comment: Tip: you can use \mid and \nmid for more nicely looking (non)divisibility relation: $p\mid n,p\nmid n$.

Comment: Thanks. Nice tip!